# Can not call Swap.AllInstances() more than once on a type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, typemock, typemock-isolator

I have a test case that has a problem where the exception in the title is thrown.

The exception is only thrown when the static methods fake is also present in the test.

My presumption is that StaticMethods fake is also doing the swap.  If this is the case, how can I fake static methods and also replace instances with my instance fake?

```
[Test]
[Isolated]
[Factory("TruckDispatchData")]
public void TruckDispatchTest(
    IEnumerable<DeliveryInfo> deliveryInfo,
    bool expectedResult)
{
    Isolate.Fake.StaticMethods(typeof(Order), Members.MustSpecifyReturnValues);
    var order = Isolate.Fake.Instance<Order>(Members.MustSpecifyReturnValues, ConstructorWillBe.Ignored, BaseConstructorWillBe.Ignored);
    Isolate.Swap.AllInstances<Order>().With(order);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work at Typemock,
Just checked this issue and I can confirm that this is a bug.
The workaround for this issue is pretty simple, you just have to switch the order of the calls. e.g.

```
var order = Isolate.Fake.Instance<Order>(Members.MustSpecifyReturnValues, ConstructorWillBe.Ignored, BaseConstructorWillBe.Ignored);
Isolate.Swap.AllInstances<Order>().With(order);
Isolate.Fake.StaticMethods(typeof(Order), Members.MustSpecifyReturnValues);
```

It will be fixed in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure, as didn't use `TypeMock` library, but I think that the problem is in your `Swap` method:

```
Isolate.Swap.AllInstances<Order>()
```

As you call the all **instances** of `Order` class, the **static** methods aren't involved (as they aren't `Order` instance methods, they are `Type` of `typeof(Order)` instance methods), so, may be, `Swap` approach can be used in some different way, something like this:

```
Isolate.Swap.Static_SOMETHING_HERE.With(order);
```

Comment: The static method faking is to allow access to the static methods of the object type as you point out.  However, the swap is only swapping the instances of the object order with the faked instance version.  I am not trying to swap a static order with an instance, I am trying to swap instance for instance, and separately access static methods of the type.  I think the implementation of StaticMethod faking must also perform a swap to get the error in question